# Can I do this with a map function?

Tags: function, python-2.7, dictionary, map-function

I'm learning about the map, filter and reduce functions. While doing an exercise I wondered if I could write it with a map function instead, I messed around a bit but I couldn't arrive at a solution. Is this possible? Any help would be appreciated.

```
for f in words:
    a = words.index(f)
    final_dict[str(words[a])] = len(pre[a])
```

words is a list of words and pre is a list of lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dict` constructor accepts an iterable of key/value pairs, so yes:

```
def to_pair(item):
    i, word = item
    return (word, len(pre[i]))

final_dict = dict(map(to_pair, enumerate(words)))
```

(Use `final_dict.update` if it already has entries.)